# How to use typescript/flow in nodejs without compiling it

Tags: node.js, typescript, flowtype

Can someone give me some advice or links for discussion on whether I should bundle JS for backend?

I tried to Google with this title (and similar words) and I can't get any useful links.

Just want to know, say I am using latest Node.JS (es6-ready), should I bundle/compile the JS? If not, how am I suppose to use typescript/flow?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I feel like you are asking two different questions. I'll try to answer both.

## How can I just run TypeScript code?

This is the one your question's title seems to ask ("How to use typescript/flow in nodejs without compiling it"). For this, you can use the [ts-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node) package on npm. But it's usually not a good idea to use ts-node over just compiling when running in production because it tends not to be as fast.

## How should TypeScript code get distributed to be run?

Any TypeScript code will need to get compiled from `.ts` files to `.js` files to eventually be run. Basically something like the same thing applies to Flow code.

If you plan to *distribute* a package written in TypeScript, you should be publishing the `.js` and `.d.ts` files together. This is so that

1. Your package consumers don't have to recompile your package. (they already get `.js` files.
2. Your non-TypeScript consumers don't need to install TypeScript to use your package. (they already have runnable `.js` files)
3. Your TypeScript consumers can get good type safety and completions. (they get your `.d.ts` files)

For more information, see the TypeScript documentation on [Publishing Declaration Files](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/publishing.html).

Comment: Thanks for your detail answer. I learned from the links. Thanks! Although I'll mark the other person's as the 'answer' since it is answered before your one and did resolve my question ( yours did as well!).

Comment: Just for clarity, even something like ts-node or babel-node are doing just-in-time transpilation. There's not a "native" ES6 or TypeScript run time that I'm aware of. If you're looking to use something like TS in a real production scenario, definitely take the advice above and deal with the compile/transpile step on the dev side, not the run time side.