# Node can run .ts files, so why use tsc to transpile to .js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

The following works on node version 12

```
node hello.ts
```

What is the point of installing

```
 npm install -g typescript
```

And then doing

```
tsc hello.ts
```

To obtain hello.js and then do

```
node hello.js
```

Is there a difference between the two? I have only tested this with minimal code. Is there a fundamentally different implementation inside node that transpiles to javascript compared to what tsc does?

Thank you

Comment: Consider that TypeScript isn't only used in a Node environment.

Comment: for typescript to work correctly it needs to compile. This question as been answered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40752666/how-to-use-typescript-flow-in-nodejs-without-compiling-it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use typescript/flow in nodejs without compiling it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40752666/how-to-use-typescript-flow-in-nodejs-without-compiling-it)

Comment: Not to mention you can't actually run TypeScript with node like that, it's possible your example is just vanilla JS in a `.ts` file in which case you can name the file `hello.abc123` and Node will run that too.

Comment: Try some TypeScript code that actually uses TypeScript only features.  That will not run in node.js without first compiling/transpiling it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you write javascript code in a ts file like:

```
console.log('Hello world');
```

nodejs will execute it, the extension .ts doesnt really matter.

TS can transpile js and ts, but when you write more complex TS constructions like:

```
class Greeter {
    constructor(private hello) {
    }
public static greet() {
    console.log(this.greet);
    }
}
Greeter.greet();
```

nodeJs will not be able to execute the code, you need to transpile it to JS to execute or use a library like [ts-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node)